# jquery load second time a partial view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to use **`jquery.load("/home/CreateEdit")`** 
from a button in a grid so each time,i want to edit a row,i load a partialView using this jquery.load.
the problem is that after i edited some date,and i want again to call the load function ,doesn't go back to the server,to reload the newly modified date.
why?
this is the purpose of load?only one time goes to server?do i have to use a get/post jquery call instead,or what is the solution?

P.S:the action is looking like this

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateEdit(int id=0)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            var model = _tallyMeasurementRepository.GetById(id);
            return PartialView("_CreateEdit", AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TallyMeasurement, TallyMeasurementViewModel>(model));
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateEdit", new TallyMeasurementViewModel());
        }

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEdit(TallyMeasurementViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            _tallyMeasurementRepository.Update(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TallyMeasurementViewModel,TallyMeasurement >(viewModel));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Measurementt");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The client is expected to make any subsequent calls after the server returns a redirect result.  The server will not send the additional data, until the client asks for it.

So, in you jquery result handler code, check if the response is a redirect; if it is make the subsequent call.

Alternatively, if you know the id of the record you are returning, you can always simply return the different result.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEdit(TallyMeasurementViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        _tallyMeasurementRepository.Update(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TallyMeasurementViewModel,TallyMeasurement >(viewModel));
    }
    return CreateEdit(id); // WHERE id is the value to load
}
```